# Laravel 5.1 Event deleting and delete not fire

Tags: php, laravel

I Works with Laravel 5.1 and works with events creating, updating, deleting. creating and updating works fine, but deleting method not fire. I have tests in Model, creating an Observer class and put into EventServiceProvider without any solution.

My code:

```php
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::deleting(function($user)
        {
            if(count($user->getImages()) >0){
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

My code delete:

```php
    User::where('id','=',$id)->delete();
```

Any suggestion? Thank for all in advance

Comment: Show code where your try to delete

Comment: The code is User::where('id','=',$id)->delete()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `User::where('id','=',$id)->first()->delete();` It must be work, I have the same bug in my project.

For multiple rows:

```php
    User::where('id', $id)->get()->each(function($row){ 
        $row->delete();
    });
```

Comment: better would be `User::find($id)->delete()`

Comment: And how return a message? If return message can't return false... Thanks Mike!!

Comment: Hi Mike, and for multiple rows?

Answer (score 0):

the next option if you shoot the events deleted, deleting

```
User::destroy(id);
```

or

```
User::destroy([id1, id2, id3]);
```

Comment: `User::destroy([id1, id2, id3]);` don't work. On a mass delete, the `deleted` and `deleting` events aren't fired.